# mysql 5.7.5 group replication configuration issues

Tags: database-replication, mysql-5.7

I want to try mysql 5.7.5 group replication over corosync.
And the corosync is running correctly.

I followed the steps on http://mysqlhighavailability.com/getting-started-with-mysql-group-replication/#comment-2058 to configure mysql-group-replication on two host, but  only  the node which first starts gcs_replication can be online, the other one is offline.

When the second node starts gcs_replication, we got the logging info from mysql server side.

```
[ERROR] Failed to open the relay log './gcs_recovery.000001' (relay_log_pos 4).
[ERROR] Could not find target log file mentioned in relay log info in the index file './gcs_recovery.index' during relay log initialization.
[ERROR] Plugin gcs_replication_plugin reported: '[Recovery:] Failed to setup the donor connection (relay log) metadata container.'
[ERROR] Plugin gcs_replication_plugin reported: '[Recovery:] Error when configuring the connection to the donor.'
[Note] Plugin gcs_replication_plugin reported: '[Recovery:] Retrying connection with another donor. Attempt 1/1'
[ERROR] Failed to open the relay log './gcs_recovery.000001' (relay_log_pos 4).
[ERROR] Could not find target log file mentioned in relay log info in the index file './gcs_recovery.index' during relay log initialization.
[ERROR] Plugin gcs_replication_plugin reported: '[Recovery:] Failed to setup the donor connection (relay log) metadata container.'
[ERROR] Plugin gcs_replication_plugin reported: '[Recovery:] Error when configuring the connection to the donor.'
[ERROR] Plugin gcs_replication_plugin reported: '[Recovery:] Maximum number of retries when trying to connect to a donor reached. Aborting recovery.'
2015-02-17T18:39:25.119836Z 0 [Note] Plugin gcs_replication_plugin reported: '[Recovery:] Marking view change with view_id 13'
```

The article said, "By default, these settings are configured to use “root” with no associated password. " Does this mean the client should login without password?
But when I login the client with `./bin/mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 13001 --prompt='server1>'`,  it shows `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, so i added "-p".

Similar issue, when I start the server, it shows `[ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!`, so I add "-u root"

I don't know weather these modifications are the reason resulting in the failure configuration. Does anyone have any experience of mysql-group-replication to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> The article said, "By default, these settings are configured to use
>   “root” with no associated password. " Does this mean the client should
>   login without password? But when I login the client with ./bin/mysql
>   -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 13001 --prompt='server1>', it shows ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   NO), so i added "-p".
>
> Similiar issue, when I start the server, it shows [ERROR] Fatal error:
>   Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run
>   mysqld as root!, so I add "-u root"

Not the client.
The article refers to the connection credentials that recovery tries to use by default to contact other servers. It will try to contact other servers with the user root and no password, but in most cases, yes, the server will not have a unprotected root user so these options must be changed. It does not means that there is such a connection in the server that you can use.

Anyway, the problem shown in the log seems to be something related to the relay log creation, hence, it should not be related to the credentials.

In my opinion you should try to use the newer version currently on labs release and see if the current improvements with the use of replication channels help you.
http://labs.mysql.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think I had similar problems regarding my relay files.
I simply did a `reset slave` then restarted with `start group_replication`.